# Why chdir("..") is not working?

Tags: php

I want to go up two directories from the current working directory.

I used `chdir("..")` **two times** to make the move. And after that I call `mkdir("directoryname")` ; but when I looked at the operating system ( Linux Ubuntu ) then the directory is not created ; even though I already set the `chmod 777` to the parent directory into which I want to create the new directory. So how to mount up two directories level with PHP ?

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error logs? Chances are there's an incredibly descriptive message in there if they're enabled.

Comment: Did you check file permissions?  i.e. does the user running the PHP process have permission to create directories in `../..`?

Comment: @trojanfoe : the user has permission , it is the root.

Comment: @Andy *root*? In a PHP script? Are you running this from the command line?

Comment: @Andy check for errors. Error log or setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` can be of great help.

Comment: How about trying `mkdir('../../directoryname')`?

Comment: @middaparka : in fact the php file is not invoked through a web browser but through a java j2me application. The page is not displayed but is used as the url parameter of a POST connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify "where" your script started and where it is after the two chdir()s via

```
echo getcwd();
```

also test the return value of mkdir

```
if ( mkdir($path) ) {
  echo 'done'.
}
else {
  echo 'failed.';
}
```

or use [getcwd()](http://docs.php.net/getcwd) or [_FILE_, _DIR_](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (or whatever is suitable) and [dirname()](http://docs.php.net/dirname) to create an abosulte path for [mkdir()](http://docs.php.net/mkdir)

```
$d = getcwd();
echo 'start: ', $d, "\n";
$d = dirname(dirname($d));
echo 'target: ', $d, "\n";

$d .= '/directoryname';
echo 'creating ', $d, "\n";
if ( mkdir($d) ) {
    echo 'done.';
}
else {
    echo 'failed.';
}
```

Comment: This is true especially for CLI scripts, the current directory is not the directory in which the file resides but that where it was executed from. In most webservers the working directory is set to the directory of the script but that is not guaranteed, so yeah you need to determine the absolute path first `dirname(__FILE__)`.